# POST data to salesforce

Tags: apex, c#, post

I am trying to POST a JSON content to an apex URL. It always returns "Method not allowed" error.

Here is the code

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://my.salesforce.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 0sdSJKBKDBK89sdfnlasd");
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "services/apexrest/myposturl");
request.Content = new StringContent(data,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(responseTask =>{Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result);});
```

Here data is json string [{},{}]

The output is

```
Response: StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1,   
Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: reflected-xss block;report-uri /_/ContentDomainCSPNoAuth?type=xss
Content-Security-Policy: referrer origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 07 Mar 2017 07:02:30 GMT
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=HoIXa_a4DFDSTasamQ;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 06-May-2017 07:02:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
}
```

When I try to pass a invalid token, it throws UnAuthorized error which is perfectly fine.

But when I pass the valid token, it always throws 'Method Not Allowed'.

The same content with same token works fine while POSTing using postman.

Comment: Sounds like there is no HTTPPost resource at that URL mapping. If you have access to the Rest class please post it as it sounds like thats where the issue is. Also, not sure on c# but do you need to append the base address or add a / in front of services or after salesforce.com?

Comment: @Eric thanks for the response. I confirmed that there is no issue with c# base address formation. As stated in the question, the same HTTP Post resource works as expected when trying with Postman :(

Comment: Postman is not c#. In the examples I saw from a google search there is a / at the end of the base URL. To me it looks like the url is constructed as `https://my.salesforce.comservices/apexrest/......` While your Postman may be typed correctly it is not using your code so.....Not saying it is the issue but I would check the URL that is being generated to be sure. If URL is correct you will need to post the Rest class as well as ensure it has an HTTPPost method

Comment: @Eric Sorry it was my mistake. As said by you, HTTP Post resource was not correct, it had spelling mistake. Thank you again!